# pymongo full text search AND

Tags: python, mongodb, full-text-search, pymongo

I am using pymongo to perform full text search on mongodb.
When I use just one word in the search, for example:

```
{ "$text": { "$search": " 'word1' "  } }
```

it works fine, but in case of `AND` (word1 and word2):

```
{ "$text": { "$search": "\"word1 word2\""  } }
```

the query execution takes a long time.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{ "$text": { "$search": "\"word1\" \"word2\""  } }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.